# emberfire: this._ref.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, ember.js, firebase-realtime-database, emberfire

**The Issue**

I seem to be getting the following error with emberfire, I followed the documentation yet still get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._ref.push is not a function
    at Class.generateIdForRecord (firebase.js:75)
    at Class._generateId (-private.js:10359)
    at Class.createRecord (-private.js:10325)
    at Class.test (home.js:13)
    at Class.send (action_handler.js:32)
    at action.js:141
    at exports.flaggedInstrument (ember-metal.js:3730)
    at action.js:140
    at Backburner.run (backburner.js:537)
    at run (ember-metal.js:4267)
```

The following code is where the error comes from, the code is simply placed in an action in a controller called home:

```
var newGlobal = this.store.createRecord('global', {
  about: 'test',
});
newGlobal.save();
```

The rules on the database are set up as:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

and the database is empty.

I have also setup `config/environment.js`

Any ideas please?

Thank you in advance

**Helpful Links**

[emberfire](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire)

[Emberfire guide](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md)

[Found these issues but they didn't help with my issue](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=this._ref.push())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved, the issue was I had created a custom ember service called `firebase`.

I had injected it in the `home` controller like so:

```
firebase: Ember.inject.service()
```